# Music app overlay with control on volume level change

Tags: music, 8.1-oreo, overlay

I'm newbie in android world (recently switched from windows phone). 
And I really miss the music overlay that comes into place when you press volume level button.

In desktop windows it looks like this, something like that on the phone.
[image]

I really miss this overlay hence it allowed to pause music fast and fluid. I can't do it now on my phone. Only option I offered is lock screen widget but it's not handy - I use my fingerpring to unlock phone and actually never see lockscreen. And while using phone I have to go into music app and switch track or use its widget. That's pretty annoing. Is there any options to have similiar with windows functionality here?

Comment: Does your music app not show a persistent notification with media playback controls? Or is it not handy too? :-)

Comment: On pressing volume key? No, it's not.

Comment: Would it be an acceptable solution if you press a volume button and the notification bar drop down on its own automatically, giving access to media controls?

Comment: That can be an option, I need to see how it works

Comment: Have a look at this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.hinterhofapps.sliderwidget

Comment: Thanks, I saw it. It's screen widget and it is not what I was looking for. I need overlay on volume button press

Comment: Anton, what Firelord meant by "persistent notification" is in the notification area – i.e. when music is playing, draw down the notification bar and look whether its in there. I'm not aware there's something like that to act on the volume rockers, so the persistent notification is possible as close as you can get.

Comment: Thanks now I got it. Yes, I do have widget in notification area but it still not what I want to. I know that it can be impossible, so I just asking if there any chance to get this overlay

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a number of media players and I don't think such a feature is offered by any of them. However, as a workaround, I offer this solution:

Whenever you would press a volume button, provided a music is playing, the status bar would automatically drop down, giving access to persistent notification of your music player along with its media controls.

Follow these instructions:

1. Install [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid).
2. Go to Accessibility settings in your Settings app and enable both the accessibility services of MacroDroid.
3. Launch MacroDroid → Add Macro:

   - **Trigger**: Volume Button Pressed → Use Accessibility Service → Volume Up → Update Volume
   - **Action**: Expand/Collapse Status Bar → Expand Status Bar
   - **Condition**: Music Active → Music Playing
4. Make an another macro with same action, same condition, same action but choose Volume Down, instead of Volume Up.
5. Play a song, and test the volume buttons.